# StringBuilder and For Loop

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**MY QUESTION:**

Is it possible to use a `StringBuilder()` inside a `for` loop?

I have this code:

```
text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c04485ed"));

                    String a = view.getTag().toString();
                    String b = text.getText().toString();
                    String formedWord = "";

                    StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();

                    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
                        word.append(b);

                        if (word.length() == wordArray[i].length()){
                            formedWord = word.toString();

                            if(formedWord.equals(wordArray[i])){
                                break;
                            }
                        }                   
                    }



                }
            });
```

**EXPLANATION OF THE CODE ABOVE**

The function of this **code** is to form a **string** from the clicked `textViews()` and `if` that word is equal to the `length()` of the string on the index i of the string `wordArray[]` the system will check `if` the formedWord is equal to the string on the same index.

**ERROR:**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.gabriel.salitaangpinoy10, PID: 8780
>                     java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=6
>                         at com.example.gabriel.salitaangpinoy10.GameScreen$2.onClick(GameScreen.java:247)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5210)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21169)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

And when I checked the

> com.example.gabriel.salitaangpinoy10.GameScreen$2.onClick(GameScreen.java:247)

It brings me to this line:

`if (word.length() == wordArray[i].length())`

Comment: You can do it like this. Could you please explain where the problem is?

Comment: @Gboy why are you incrementing `i++;` inside the for-loop again?

Comment: What's happening here is you are continuing to add `b` to `word` so the first iteration `b` might hold "value" and the second iteration `b` would hold "valuevalue" and so on.  This is why you are having trouble matching word length

Comment: @TobiasOtto see the edit on my question. I added the **ERROR** part.

Comment: @khelwood see the **ERROR** part. I edited my question. Thanks

Comment: @CraigR8806 so what should be the possible solution? should i bring the `word.append(b);` outside the `for` loop?

Comment: That's nothing to do with how you're using a StringBuilder. You're going outside the bounds of your array.

Comment: Does your `wordArray` have length less than 11 ?

Comment: You could just check the length of `b` against your `wordArray[i]` length

@khelwood is correct as well that you are going outside of your array

Comment: @khelwood none. the maximum length of the strings inside the `wordArray` is 10

Comment: @Gboy The issue is not the maximum length of strings inside the `wordArray`. The issue is the length of `wordArray`.

Comment: @khelwood oh i see! the size of the `wordArray` depends on the selection of the user: 5, 8, or 10. So i should set the "10" on `i<=10` to `i<=userSelectedInteger`?

Comment: @Gboy It needs to be `<`, not `<=`. I suggest `i < wordArray.length` .

Comment: @khelwood i tried to modify code to see if I can get the output but it doesn't display the Log.

Here is the code:

`StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
                        word.append(b);

                        if(word.length() == wordArray[0].length()){
                            formedWord = word.toString();
                            Log.e("formedWord:", formedWord);
                        }`

Comment: wordArray.length==5. But you try to get wordArray[6]. Where only wordArray[0] to wordArray[4] are valid. You did not even post how you defined wordArray.

Comment: @greenapps wordArray is programmatically defined. Its items are from another array

Comment: You should of course show us how it is defined. But why arent you reacting on the explanation i gave you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the below line from your code snippet. It has condition i <= 10 which means loop will run ten times if not broken. How did you know that the loop has to run till count of 10. Probably you should derive the loop counter value from event text length being passed to the method or it should be something like i <= wordArray.length to avoid exception

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
```

Comment: The answer from Shrinu Namburu is the right clue, but this for-loop will run 11 times.

Comment: @TobiasOtto what should I do if i want the appended `StringBuilder()` to pass the formed string to another variable?

Comment: `like i <= wordArray.length to avoid exception`. ? You mean i < wordArray.length i think.